# How to under-line selected text in JtextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I want to make selected text of jtextarea underline while clicking a spicified button. this task I have accomplish in jtextpane but I need it in jtextarea any suggestions please.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `JTextPane` (or `JEditorPane`), where you can use `HTML` tags to accomplish that.

The text of a `JTextArea` **cannot** be formatted in parts, as indicated [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html), for example:

> A `JTextArea` is a multi-line area that displays **plain text**.

Comment: this can also be done with a label: `new JLabel("<html><u>abc<br>def")` - actually having more than one line [:-)

Comment: you probably cant Read: " I have accomplish in jtextpane"

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make selected text of jtextarea underline

You can add a `Highlighter` to the text area and use a custom `Painter` to highlight the text. The default painter paints the entire background of the highlighted text, but you can customize the Painter to do whatever you want.

Check out [Rectangle Painter](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/rectangle-painter/) for a couple examples of creating your own custom `Painter`.